# Grouping jQuery AJAX requests to enforce order

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I am using jQuery to launch multiple AJAX requests, and need to group them so that the requests from Batch 1 are completely executed before those from Batch 2 start. The JSFiddle illustrating this is at http://jsfiddle.net/ax5mty3q/ . The relevant code is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var deferreds = GetSomeDeferredStuff("def1");
        var deferreds2 = GetSomeDeferredStuff("def2");

        var base = $.when({});

        base = base.then($.when.apply(null, deferreds));

        // I want to stop here until def1 batch is completed

        base = base.then($.when.apply(null, deferreds2).done(function() {
            $("div").append("<p>All done!</p>");
        }));
    });
});
```

The issue is that the second batch starts before the first batch finishes. But the way the code currently works, I get batch 2 jobs starting before batch 1 is completed:

```
Click me!
def1: Task #1 complete.
def1: Task #2 complete.
def1: Task #3 complete.
def1: Task #4 complete.
def1: Task #5 complete.
def1: Task #6 complete.
def2: Task #1 complete.
def2: Task #2 complete.
def1: Task #7 complete.
def2: Task #3 complete.
def1: Task #8 complete.
def1: Task #9 complete.
def2: Task #4 complete.
def2: Task #5 complete.
def1: Task #10 complete.
def2: Task #6 complete.
def2: Task #7 complete.
def2: Task #8 complete.
def2: Task #9 complete.
def2: Task #10 complete.
All done!
```

Is there a way I can control the second batch before the first batch is completely done? In other words, def2: Task #1 should appear only after def1: Task #10 is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only call `GetSomeDeferredStuff("def2")` inside the `base.then`. You can also use `Promise.all` instead to greatly simplify the code, since deferreds work as Promises:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  var deferreds = GetSomeDeferredStuff("def1");
  Promise.all(deferreds)
    .then(() => Promise.all(GetSomeDeferredStuff("def2")))
    .then(() => {
      $("div").append("<p>All done!</p>");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // something went wrong, handle errors
    });
});
```

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks! Will accept your answer as soon as SO lets me. I was trying to stick to jQuery deferred functions but there is no reason to do so, and this works as advertised.

Comment: By the way, I did try using GetSomeDeferredStuff("def2") inside base.then and it did not resolve the issue. Using Promise.all is what did the trick.

Comment: Should've clarified, I meant inside the *second* `.then`, eg `base.then(() => { var deferreds2 = ... $.when.apply(null, deferreds2).done(() {`